# refactor calls to a bunch of constructors that all take the same args

Tags: c#, constructor, refactoring

How would I refactor this:

```
if (cond1) {
    return new Class1(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
else if (cond2) {
    return new Class2(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
else if (cond3) {
    return new Class3(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
...
```

I'm particularly interested in avoiding repeating `arg1, arg2, arg3`

Comment: It might be (quite) helpful to add what language you're aiming at...

Answer (score 1):

Make a factory function:

```
template<class Derived>
Base* instantiate(A arg1, B arg2, C arg3) {
    return new Derived(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Build a map using a key type that makes sense:

```
std::map<int, Base(*)(A, B, C)> factory;

factory[0] = instantiate<Class1>;
factory[1] = instantiate<Class2>;
factory[2] = instantiate<Class3>;
```

Yes, for `int` this could be just an array or `std::vector`, but I use `std::map` above for the sake of offering a generic solution. You can then obtain instances from the factory in the obvious fashion. For arbitrary conditions, it’d have to be something like this:

```
int index = cond1 ? 0
    : cond2 ? 1
    : cond3 ? 2
    : throw std::runtime_error("Invalid index.");

return factory[index](arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

But there’s probably a saner way to do it based on the specifics of your problem.

Comment: +1. This is C++, but exactly the same approach applies to C#.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Oops. The question wasn’t tagged as such and I just assumed. I’ll leave it as-is though, because the factory pattern is portable between those languages.

Comment: You could do the same with Action<A,B,C> in a Dicitionary; where Action<A,B,C> points to the constructor with those same arguments in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***Activator***.

```
Type t = cond1 ? typeof(Class1) : cond2 ? typeof(Class2) : cond3 ? typeof(Class3) : null;
Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] {arg1, arg2, arg3});
```

Comment: Also may want to add check for `t != null`